# onClick() Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onclick

I have two links on my html page which when clicked runs a script using 'onClick'. the code worked perfectly before but after I added some code then removed it, it has stopped working.

**Link**

```
<a id="log" class="btn btn-xs" href="#" onclick="Options.js">Change Log</a>
```

**Options.js**

```
document.getElementById('log').addEventListener('click', showLog);

function showLog() {
var log = window.open("", "title", "srollbars=0, width=440, height=620");
var src = "../changelog/changelog.txt";

log.document.write('<p><iframe src="'+src+'" width=430 height=600 frameborder=0></iframe></p>');
}
```

The code seems slightly finicky. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does `onclick="showLog()"` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a id="save" class="btn btn-xs" href="#" onclick="Options.js">Change Log</a>
```

Should be

```
<a id="save" class="btn btn-xs" href="#" onclick="showLog()">Change Log</a>
```

You've referenced the script file not the function, providing you've included your options.js somewhere in your html document

I.e. the snippet below is present in the html document somewhere

```
<script src="js/Options.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

onClick expects a function, not a file.
Import your file first, then call your function like showLog(); in the onclick segment.